# How to build mixed c/c++ program completely static

Tags: clang, clang++, llvm-c++-api, musl

I have project with C and C++ code which I want to build as single `.so` library and use it in my Java program with [Panama](https://openjdk.org/projects/panama/).
On my computer it works fine, but in CI it fails because of `GLIBC` and `GLIBCXX` version mismatch.

AFAIK better way to fix it is static linking.

And I found flags to statically link `GLIBCXX`: `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`.

But `GLIBC` doesn't support static linking. And fails on build with `-static` flag like this:

```
usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a(malloc.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against `tcache' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: bad value
```

I know there is `libc` [implementation in llvm](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/libc) which supports static linking. But I can't find a way how to force clang use it, something like `-static-llvm-libc`.

Also there are `musl` which supports static linking too.
But flag `--target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` doesn't force to use it somehow. And build with `-static` still fails and I see with `ldd` `glibc` in dependencies.